# Is there a way to change the formatting of a single word in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

just a quick question but I can't figure out if it's just not possible, (which is fine, workaround is easy enough just time consuming), or if I'm too blind to see it.

For example, I want to put one word in a text in **Bold**, or in a different color. Is there any way? I'm used to this functionality in Photoshop, I'm sure you guys know what I mean.

If it's not there, what's the best workaround? Just put a bunch of spaces in there and make a new text-layer with the word and the different formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in Gimp. In the workaround, you may want to make an extra layer that contains all your text; it is normally hidden, but can be turned on in order to properly align your visible layers.

Comment: that's a good tip man, (and if nothing else shows up I'll select this answer)

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using Gimp 2.8.4.

A word inside a text box can be selected and by clicking on the bold icon and the colour selector on the toolbar above the textbox, the required attributes can be set.

[image: Gimp TextBox word emphasis]